# Problum with mysqld

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I'm running Ubuntu server 12.04 on a computer at home, granted it's a netbook so there's not a lot of performance to squeeze out of it, but I'm still wondering about the memory usage I'm seeing from /usr/sbin/mysqld.